# Toon shader only applied to part of the mesh

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

[image: Toon rendering on select parts of model]

I had wanted to add some toon shading or so to my model, but I've come to a problem where it's only rendering on parts of the body. They're all different segments, but they're all joined. Is it something I can fix, or did I mess up somewhere?

The blend was asked for, so if I'm doing this right, here ya' go

[image]

Comment: This could be a multitude of things, are all these pieces one object, does the material depend on normals, are they consistent.. etc. etc.. I think you're going to have to share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , editing the link into your post, to give us a chance.

Comment: In your file, half the faces are assigned the material 'Body' and half, 'Material'. What happens, if you select *all* faces, and in the material tab, select 'Body', and click Assign?

Comment: Well, yeah that fixed it. Not entirely sure how that happened to those and not the rest, but thank you.

Comment: When you join objects, they keep the material slots already assigned.